# How to change a button's visibility in VB6?

Tags: vb6

**THE SITUATION**

I am developing a VB6 application where all i need to do is to sync some files from a server location to the local workstation on a command click. There are two types of operations i am performing, in one m doing a complete sync, in the other i am doing a partial sync. Now when the sync is in progress i am displaying a screen which has a stop button on it. This stop is meant to stop the copying of media if the user wants to do so.

Now, this stop button is only visible when i am performing full sync. There is no option to stop the sync when partial sync is being performed.

The functions performing full sync and partial sync are written in a different class.

**THE PROBLEM :**

I have implemented all other functions but i having a problem in making this stop button dynamic..i.e. it is visible when full sync is bein called and invisible when partial sync is called.

Hope somebody helps

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's simply a matter of setting the `.Visible` property when you're doing a full sync. Which part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3):

Set the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445768%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) property to False to hide the button.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, since the stop button is on a separate form it is not the case that there are other buttons on top of it- I had similar case myself.

What I can suggest is to check is whether both of the sync buttons are enabling the stop's button visibility when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it something like this:

```
Private sub cmdFullSync_Click()
'run existing code for a full sync
cmdStop.visible = true
end Sub

Private sub cmdPartialSync_Click()
'run existing partial sync code
cmdstop.visible = false
end Sub
```